# How to insert a function call at the very end of the module in LLVM pass?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

My pass inserts functions at certain points and those functions gather some information. At the end of the module I want to display whatever I gathered long the way, so I want to insert a function at the end of the module that will do the printing job for me. I have trouble detecting the very end of the module to insert the function right before it. Help and guidance will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you wanting to output this at the end of the module?  Or do you mean that you want to output prior to the program's termination?

Comment: Prior to the programs termination.

Comment: You should look at using atexit().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no easy and simple way of doing this.You need to look for two kinds of exit points in the code.

1) The code can have calls to functions like `exit()` which would be the exit point of the program. So you need to look for those in the pass and insert your function call before them. If you don't want to go through the trouble to check each and every instruction in the code, then may be you can manually replace the calls to `exit()` in the code function with a new exit function (something like `exit_())` which contains the call to the function that you want to call followed by the actual call to the `exit()` function. This latter approach requires that you have access to the code beforehand.

2) The program will exit at the end of the entry function (usually `main`). So, you can check if the function name is same as the potential entry point function or not and insert the function call before the return statement. If it doesn't have return statement then insert it at the end of all the instructions.

Comment: Right. Thanks for your detailed reply. So no matter how the program comes to termination, the function called for the termination to ocur is exit() so I can replace it or insert my function before the exit() instruction?

Comment: Yes, you can insert your calls before ```exit()``` and you also need to take care of the entry function as described in point 2 in the answer above.

Comment: Yup. So the name of the function where exit is should the entry one i.e. main()?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: Oh let me clarify. So the function where exit() is, before which I plan to insert my own function, should be in the entry function i.e. main()?

Comment: No, exit() call can be anywhere in the code. You have to go through every instruction in the code and look for call to exit function and insert you thing before it. In addition to this, you also have to insert your function before the end of the main() function (a.k.a. the entry function) because that's also an exit point for the code.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and more complete solution would be to take advantage of llvm's destructor functionality, by appending your code as a destructor in the @llvm.global_dtor list.  There is a library to aid with this (the addToGobalDtors function in Transforms/Utils/ModuleUtils.h).

Once your function is appended to the dtor list, it will automatically be called on program exit (as any C++-style global destructor would).

Comment: It's now (or always has been?) `appendToGlobalDtors()`.